# Getting a 'InvalidComObjectException' on exit?

Tags: c#, exception, crystal-reports

After viewing a Crystal Reports document in C#, the application gives this error when exiting.

I've called the Close() and Dispose() methods on the report.

From what I've read, this is happening because a COM object is being called after it's unloaded, but I can't see how or where this is happening.

Has anyone seen this before? Or could you recommend a tool to track down the problem?

Thanks!

[Edit]

Stack-trace when the exception is thrown:

> CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll!CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ISCDClientDocumentEvents_EventProvider.RemoveOnClosed(CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc._ISCDClientDocumentEvents_OnClosedEventHandler handler) + 0x137 bytes
>       CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll!CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ISCDClientDocumentEvents_EventProvider.OnClosed.remove(CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc._ISCDClientDocumentEvents_OnClosedEventHandler value) + 0x33 bytes
>       CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll!CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.DisconnectEventRelay() + 0x75 bytes 
>       CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll!CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.InternalClose(bool bSetupForNextReport, bool bAutoClose) + 0x10e bytes
>       CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll!CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.Dispose(bool bDisposeManaged) + 0xb6 bytes
>       System.dll!System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose() + 0x15 bytes
>       CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll!CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.ClearCache(bool clearDocument) + 0x1dd bytes
>       CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll!CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.InternalClose(bool bSetupForNextReport) + 0x81 bytes
>       CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll!CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Close() + 0x3f bytes
>       CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll!CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.ExitHandler(object sender, System.EventArgs e) + 0x120 bytes
>       kernel32.dll!75e6339a()
>       [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for kernel32.dll]
>       ntdll.dll!77269ef2()
>       ntdll.dll!77269ec5()

Comment: Enable all exceptions in VS -> Debug -> Exceptions and launch in debug

Comment: If you can't provide better details, like the stack trace and a snippet, then contact the vendor for support.  Send them a small project that reproduces this exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you are disposing a Com object you must call the `COMObjects` Release method which is like this

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject( YourComObjects Name );
```

Comment: I'm not actually sure what the COM object is called, where can I find this?

Comment: what is the name of the Crystal Reports object that you are instantiating..? that's the COM Object.. can you show code.. if so I can edit / show you where to place the line of code..

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this was caused by threading - the form showing the report was in a seperate thread, and the exception was thrown when the main thread exits.

If anyone else has this problem, try using Crystal Reports only in the main thread.